# Implication in Structures like"What money he gave me"

Tags: free-relative-clauses

I understand that there is usually such implication as:

> I took what money he gave me.
>   =I took what **little** money he gave me.

But I also read the following sentence :

> What money he could lay his hands on he spent like an Indian rajah.

[source](https://sites.google.com/site/kenocstuff/the-monster)

I doubt that it has such implication , because an indian rajah is very rich.So I want to make sure if this structure **necessarily** means "there being only a little."

Comment: You will find numerous examples and explanations of the expression online, eg https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lay+one%27s+hands+on

Comment: Even in this example, there is still the implication that he wanted more, and if he could have got even more, he would have spent it.

Comment: @Colin Fine: I think *as a general principle*, if there's no explicitly-specified adjective, ***what X** [exists]* normally implies *there isn't much X*. But to me at least, that implication can be much weaker (or entirely absent) with ***whatever X** [exists]*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are *almost* correct about the implication of the first example. "*I took what money he gave me*" implies that the money was *insufficient*, or *short* for some specific purpose. That isn't quite the same as "little money". For example, $900 is not a small sum of money for most people, but it would be insufficient if you really needed $1000.

The second example is a little harder to explain. "*What money he could lay his hands on he spent*" is really saying that 'he' spent *everything* he had. The only implication is that perhaps the money was not sufficient for *him*, because he spent it "*like an Indian Rajah*". Overall, I understand it to imply the person spent money with abandon, *as if he were rich*, even though he was not rich - that he *lived beyond his means*.

Comment: Classic example - Mike Tyson.  Even with career earnings approaching a billion dollars, he spent *what money he had* "like an Indian Rajah" and ended up [declaring bankruptcy](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport2/hi/boxing/3120237.stm).